# MySql retrieve list of last known locations for all users

Tags: mysql

So in my database, I track last known GPS latitude and longitude for each user when they log in so I can then use this data later on to contact those who have a last known location within a certain radius of a specific GPS location. In order to do this, I first need to get a list of the last known location for all users that exist in my database.

Here is the query for my view:

```
SELECT u.email, l.latitude, l.longitude
from user u 
left join locationhistory l
on u.userid = l.userId
    WHERE (u.userId, l.userId) = 
    (Select userId, MAX(l.locationDate) 
    FROM locationHistory 
    GROUP BY userId)
group by email
```

The error I am receiving is:
    #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Obviously... I want a full list, why doesn't this work? I feel like I'm missing something really basic, but I am clearly just losing steam.

Thanks!

Comment: That's because your asking where a value equals a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subquery does indeed return more than one value when the where clause expects one single value. One solution is to change the query to use a join instead.

```
SELECT u.email, l.latitude, l.longitude
FROM user u 
JOIN locationhistory l ON u.userid = l.userId
JOIN (
   SELECT userId, MAX(locationDate) max_locationdate
   FROM locationHistory 
   GROUP BY userId
) x ON u.userId = x.userid AND l.locationdate = x.max_locationdate
```

Edit: I think I made a mistake and filtered out users without locations by accident... if you want all users to show up even if they don't have any records in the locationhistory table then the query you want is most likely this:

```
SELECT u.email, l2.latitude, l2.longitude
FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT l1.* FROM locationhistory l1
  JOIN (
    SELECT userId, MAX(locationDate) max_locationdate
    FROM locationHistory 
    GROUP BY userId
  ) x ON l1.locationdate = x.max_locationdate AND l1.userId = x.userid
) l2 ON u.userid = l2.userId
```

Comment: @bryanx Happy to help. I think I made a small mistake though and I've updated my answer to correct it.